# Url Rewrite => Internal Server Error

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mode

I am getting internal server errors every time i implement this code for mod-rewriting in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ /index.php?site=$1 [L]
```

I am trying to convert:

```
www.mydomain.com/index.php?site=mysite
```

to

```
www.mydomain.com/mysite.php
```

The error:

```
Internal Server Error
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule is causing an infinite loop because it's rewriting all requests ending in `.php`. This includes `index.php` too and so it ends up rewriting it to `index.php` again and again and so on..

Just add a condition to your rule that excludes it.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.php$ /index.php?site=$1 [L]
```